# Difficulty with Copy and Paste using cell's address

Tags: excel, variables, range, copy-paste, vba

I am trying to copy a group of cells from one worksheet to another. However I need to make sure it goes in the right space by double checking the month. My initial thought is to find the last value, check the date in which it occurs, then if it is the required date, declare a new variable and pass that variables address to the copy and paste code. But the code fails at the copy and paste area, which I think is a result of how I define the variables, but I need a much smarter mind than mine to figure out where I am going wrong. Thoughts?

```
Sub perfupdate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sh1, sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh1= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    Set sh2= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")

    Dim datecell As Date
    datecell = sh2.Range("a2").End(xlToRight).Offset(-1, 1).Value

    Dim dc As Range
    Set dc= sh2.Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Offset(-1, 1)
    dcadd = dc.Address

    If Month(datecell) = Month(today) And Year(datecell) = Year(today) Then
        actcell = sh2.Range(dcadd).Offset(0, -1)
    Else
        actcell = sh2.Range(dcadd)
    End If


    sh1.Range("BB3", "BB7").Copy Destination:=sh2.Range(actcell.Address).Offset(1, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: `acell` is never declare nor is it set as a range anywhere in the code.

Comment: what should I declare it as? Range?

Comment: yes, otherwise `.Address` will not work.  Also it is not set to a range anywhere in your code.  You have `actcell` getting a value of a cell but no `acell`

Comment: Yes I changed the name and forgot to change it everywhere

Comment: Right now `actcell` is a variant that is a value and `.Address` is not a child.  You need to `Set` a range.  All variables should be declared.  Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.  It would have caught the typo error.